# Electric Charge enclosed in a sphere using vector calculus

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

I'm trying to do a past exam paper on electromagnetism for communications. One of the questions is as follows:

> You are required to find the charge enclosed within the surface $\partial V$ of a sphere $V$ of radius $R$ centered at the origin of coordinates $(0, 0, 0)T$ due to an electrostatic field described by the equation
>
> $E = i (x^3 + 2x(y)^2 + 2x(z)^2 
> > +j ((y)^3 + 2y(z)^2 + 2y(x)^2) +k ((z)^3 + 2z(x)^2 + 2z(y)^2)$
>
> - Which of Maxwell’s equations is needed for this task, and how is
>     it used?
> - How can you verify that there are no time dependent
>     magnetic fields present in this situation?
>
> You will find the parameterisation $\alpha : (r, \theta, \varphi) \to (x, y, z)$ of the
>   sphere $V x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq R_2$ in terms of spherical polar coordinates
>   $(r, \theta, \varphi)$ useful, where $\theta$ and $\varphi$ are the co-latitudinal (polar) and longitudinal (azimuthal) angles:
>
> $x = r \sin \theta \cos \varphi$
>
> $y = r \sin \theta \sin \varphi$
>
> $z = r \cos \theta$,
>
> and $r = R$ on the surface. You will find that using $\int\partial V \omega = \int Vd\omega$
>
> duly specialized for the appropriate differential forms $\omega$ simplifies
>   the calculations.

This is what i think i need to do:

-We use Gauss Law

-We know by definition for Gauss law $\int\partial V \ E dA = \delta (dot product) E = Q/e0 $

-$ surface area of a sphere is dA = r^2sin(\theta)d\theta d\varphi$

ok so find div of E, then prove its electrostatic with curl E = 0,

with the div E we do a surface integral for a sphere replacing the remaining x,y,z with the corresponding r phi and theta, some cos and sin will cancel out and after surface integral and replacing r = R i have E = 4e0(pi)(R)^4 this is the enclosed electric field = enclosed charge by definition of Gauss law

is this the right method? I'm getting confused with the surface integral part.

Answer (score 1):

Use Gauß's law $\iiint\nabla.\vec{E}\mathrm{d}V=\frac{q}{\epsilon}$

Here $\mathrm{d}V=r^2\sin{\theta}\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta\mathrm{d}\phi$